# How to create surefire report in EXCEL format using Maven?

Tags: junit, maven-surefire-plugin, surefire

We have been using surefire for our JUNIT test and the report comes in a nice HTML format.
My requirement is, if there is a way we can get the report in excel format with all the file names and test failures and other details, so that the architects can filter the files and find the reasons.
I am currently using maven for the reports and the below for creating report using the 'mvn site' command
`<reporting>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
           <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
           <version>2.3-VISTAPATCH-1.4</version>
           <reportSets>
                <reportSet>
                   <configuration>
                        <aggregate>true</aggregate>
                        <showSuccess>false</showSuccess>
                   </configuration>
                   <reports>
                        <report>report-only</report>
                   </reports>
               </reportSet>
           </reportSets>
       </plugin>
     </plugins>
</reporting>`

Comment: Somebody please help me in this regards.
Is there any way to do so ?

Comment: did you solve this problem? If so kindly provide the solution here.

Comment: No, did not get any answer yet. It will be good if you can help in this.